# Unable to run and get output from ML model after publishing on Azure function app

Tags: python, machine-learning, azure-functions, modulenotfounderror

I have successfully tested ML model on jupyter notebook and generated a .py file to be used for deployment on Azure function app. However, after publishing the function app when I tried to test run it, the following error is thrown: [image: Error during test run of function app]

The `__init__.py` file is unable to find the module where the ML model is written. My file structure looks something like this:

[image: Folder structure]

Also at one point, the app was able to read the module but then it threw error for various lines of code. I am unable to understand what exactly the error is. Is my method of deployment or execution wrong?

Can anyone guide me on what am I missing or doing something wrong? Also I am new to Azure and deploying function app using Python for the first time. So any help/suggestion would be very useful.

Answer (score 0):

Thank you  @**[gaurcs](https://github.com/gaurcs)** Posting your [suggestion](https://github.com/Azure/azure-functions-python-worker/issues/626) as an answer to help other community members.

"**How to deploy a Python Function in Linux Consumption Plan**. The docs are various in nature and tells a different story. From what I see, I am  [running from a deployment package](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/run-functions-from-deployment-package) . What it does is build everything and mounts it to /home/site/wwwroot/ folder.

So what you have to do is pack everything before you publish like this below cmd:

`pip3.7 install --target $(System.DefaultWorkingDirectory)/.python_packages/lib/site-packages -r requirements.txt` "

For more information please refer the below links:

MS DOC: [Deploy a machine learning model to Azure Functions](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/machine-learning/how-to-deploy-functions) & [Deploy machine learning models to Azure](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/machine-learning/how-to-deploy-and-where?tabs=python)

BLOG: [Full Stack Machine Learning on Azure](https://towardsdatascience.com/full-stack-machine-learning-on-azure-f0f6b77be07e)